# Highcharts JS: Sankey series are stacking on top of each other rather than after each other

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to show five different series (all as Sankey types) within one chart area. I would like for the charts to appear one after the other, however, when I use the following code, the charts are stacked on top of each other.

```
Highcharts.chart('chart', {

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Sankey Diagram'
    },

    series: [
        {
            curveFactor: 0,
            data: [
                {
                    from: 'Category 1',
                    to: 'Category 2',
                    weight: 5
                }, {
                    from: 'Category 2',
                    to: 'Category 3',
                    weight: 5
                }
            ],
            type: 'sankey'
        },
        {
            data: [
                {
                    from: 'Category 4',
                    to: 'Category 5',
                    weight: 5,
                    total: 400
                }, {
                    from: 'Category 5',
                    to: 'Category 6',
                    weight: 5
                }, {
                    from: 'Category 6',
                    to: 'Category 7',
                    weight: 5
                }, {
                    from: 'Category 7',
                    to: 'Category 8',
                    weight: 5
                }
            ],
            type: 'sankey'
        }
    ],

    chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#26303A'
    }

});
```

I've tried setting `stacking: null` in `plotOptions.series`, but that seems to have no effect as that's the default value anyway.

Comment: I think you don't want to use Sankey at all.. it's a different dataset for this chart. See my comment in your other question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48414898/highchart-bar-chart-showing-duration-between-events