# Highchart: Bar chart showing duration between events

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I need to create a chart that shows a series of events (see image, in this case 6) that have a duration of time between them.

I've been able to approximate this with a sankey chart and `curveFactor:0`, but I can't seem to adjust the space between each node.

Is there some way I can achieve this? It doesn't have to be sankey chart. I can use anything in the Highcharts library. I'd also considered a stacked bar chart but ran into another set of issues.

[image: visualization of intended chart]

Comment: You should provide your code and it would be great to create a DEMO

Comment: I suggest to use [xrange](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/x-range-series) series with just one category + dataLabels. I would also consider using `Axis.plotBands` to show duration label.